# how to format date field in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

All,

I need to retrieve the date in some specific format in MYSQL. 
For eg,

it should return month/year(10/2009).

My MYSQL version is 5.1.

Thanks,
Srinivasan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function

```
DATE_FORMAT(col,'%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for this function in MySQL

[DATE_FORMAT(date, format)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
DATE_FORMAT(col, '%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date_format(yourdatefield, '%c/%Y') as formatted_date
```

will do that- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 1):

For IIS, I just use a function:

```
FUNCTION mySLQDate(xdate)
    IF xdate <> "" THEN
        mySLQDate = year(xdate) & "/" & month(xdate) & "/" & day(xdate)
    END IF
END FUNCTION
```

Answer (score 1):

use DATE_FORMAT function

http://www.mysqlformatdate.com will help you use the function properly