# How do I format a date column in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime, formatting

My query returns the row value as "2/27/2010 12:00:00 AM" but I need to get "2/27/2010".  What do I use to get the format as I need it for MySQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to format date field in MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542189/how-to-format-date-field-in-mysql)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(your_date_column, '%c/%d/%Y') FROM table
```

Comment: if column type is date/datetime/timestamp all you have to do is:
UPDATE table SET date_column = NOW()

If you need special formatting:
UPDATE table SET date_column = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%c/%d/%Y')