# Format date in MySQL to return MonthName, Year

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have rows in a table that I need to order by date. Easy enough, use the `date` datatype to store them, `ORDER BY` date blah blah.

However, I'm trying to get these rows, and easily convert the date to `MonthName, Year`

If I had stored a row's date as `2011-11-16`, I would want to extract this (using PHP) and print out:

```
 November, 2011
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to format date field in MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542189/how-to-format-date-field-in-mysql)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%M %Y') AS showdate FROM table
```

Answer (score 12):

You can get date year and monthName formate using the following query.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2017-06-15", "%Y %M") as 'Date';
```

If you need other formats apply following combinations.

Syntax: `DATE_FORMAT(date, format_mask)`

```
Format  Description
%a  Abbreviated weekday name (Sun to Sat)
%b  Abbreviated month name (Jan to Dec)
%c  Numeric month name (0 to 12)
%D  Day of the month as a numeric value, followed by suffix (1st, 2nd, 3rd, ...)
%d  Day of the month as a numeric value (01 to 31)
%e  Day of the month as a numeric value (0 to 31)
%f  Microseconds (000000 to 999999)
%H  Hour (00 to 23)
%h  Hour (00 to 12)
%I  Hour (00 to 12)
%i  Minutes (00 to 59)
%j  Day of the year (001 to 366)
%k  Hour (0 to 23)
%l  Hour (1 to 12)
%M  Month name in full (January to December)
%m  Month name as a numeric value (00 to 12)
%p  AM or PM
%r  Time in 12 hour AM or PM format (hh:mm:ss AM/PM)
%S  Seconds (00 to 59)
%s  Seconds (00 to 59)
%T  Time in 24 hour format (hh:mm:ss)
%U  Week where Sunday is the first day of the week (00 to 53)
%u  Week where Monday is the first day of the week (00 to 53)
%V  Week where Sunday is the first day of the week (01 to 53). Used with %X
%v  Week where Monday is the first day of the week (01 to 53). Used with %X
%W  Weekday name in full (Sunday to Saturday)
%w  Day of the week where Sunday=0 and Saturday=6
%X  Year for the week where Sunday is the first day of the week. Used with %V
%x  Year for the week where Monday is the first day of the week. Used with %V
%Y  Year as a numeric, 4-digit value
%y  Year as a numeric, 2-digit value
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_col, '%M, %Y')
FROM   tbl
-- WHERE ??
ORDER  BY date_col;
```

The [manual knows more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html) about that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in php:

```
<?=format_date($column_name['date'],"M, Y")?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you could get

```
SELECT year(DBDate), month(DBDate) FROM dates ORDER BY DBDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get date in mysql, use this in php

```
$date = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT date FROM table"),0,0);
echo date("F, Y", strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`,\'%M %Y\') AS showdate FROM `allowances`";
```